# How to use GAE Memcache in procedural style?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, memcached

I'm trying to connect to my Memcache instance using `memcache_connect`, but there is no hostname provided. How can I connect to my instance using a procedural style?

Comment: Can you add the code that your using to the question.

Comment: @NigelRen Currently I can't even start to code because I don't know the host of my GAE Memcache.